# What do the values for the range list in a plot in Shiny represent?

Tags: r, shiny

Taking the following example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-advanced.html

If one hovers the cursor over the plot, there's some information being displayed in a table on the right-hand side. I understand x and y are the coordinates of the cursor within the domain, which is another list of 4 values specified further below. What do the values in the range list represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain represents the extents of values in the original data observation space. The range represents the pixel extents for those data extents. This allows you to map any data value into a pixel location.